# Moving data from random cells to specific cells in another google worksheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a, create a PDF script for sales orders, and before it creates a PDF I would like to capture data in key cells (F5, G5, A11, A22 and C25:C46 where C25:C46 may only have information on 1, some, or all lines) and post that information on another google worksheet using columns A, B, C, D and E and move down to the last line +1 from the max lines E has taken from (C25:C46) when the script is ran again.

I am also trying to figure out how to bypass or give a warning option (no email present) before the script finishes so I can go back and add an email or skip that portion of the script if no email is provided.

I am new to this so I have either looked too long to where I am asking the wrong questions when doing a search or this is a new question.  Please see attached script I am currently using.

```
  function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('create PDF').addItem('create PDF','createpdf').addToUi()

 }

function createpdf() {
// Get active spreadsheet.
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// get active sheet and specific cell data
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sales Order Form");
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
sourceSheet.getRange(5, 6).getValue();
sourceSheet.getRange(5, 7).getValue();
sourceSheet.getRange(11, 1).getValue();
sourceSheet.getRange(22, 1).getValue();
var tsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...').getSheetByName("PO Log");
sourceRange.copyTo(tsheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+("D"+(last_row+1));

// Get active sheet.
var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName(); 
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

// Set the output filename as SheetName.
var pdfName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A11").getValue()

// Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
if (parents.hasNext()) {
  var folder = parents.next();
}
else {
  folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}

// Copy whole spreadsheet.
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).
makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf",folder))

// Delete redundant sheets.
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
  destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
  }
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// Repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),
sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

// Save to pdf.
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  var file = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName("Sales Order/Invoice").getAs(MimeType.PDF);
var email = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A16").getValue(); 
var subject = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
var body = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A12").getValue();
  
MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"\nThank you for your purchase/inquiry. Attached is your Sales Order/Invoice.\n\nThank You\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...", 
{attachments: [file],
name: 'Sales Order/Invoice'});

// Delete the temporary sheet.
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A11:E11').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('H47').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('A22:H22').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('C25:D46').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B18:G19').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('G25:G46').clearContent();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("SO tally counter").getRange('A2').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("SO tally counter").getRange('A2').getValue() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Since the code looks a little bit like it was written by Victor Frankenstein it would be easer to rewrite it from the scratch, if you will provide a sample of your data and a sample of desired output. The task to copy a couple cells from a sheet to sheet and send a PDF is quite simple, it isn't worth as a script for a horror movie

Comment: Ha, Victor Frankenstein!  Love it.  Yeah I am less than a beginner to this.  All of the script used has been pieced together from what I have found online.  Thanks for the response.  I did end up adding  "return false;" to the end of the email alert to stop the script from running any further if no email.  The last line script worked with one exception.  I was hoping columns A-D would start at the first line +1 of column E since E may have more rows filled in where A-D only use a single row.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

#### Since you want to copy multiple different values, the best situation would actually be to handle each column/value separately.

Taking this into account, I have taken the opportunity to modify the part of your script which handles the copying of the values:

```
function createpdf() {

    let sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sales Order Form");
    let valuesC = sourceSheet.getRange(25, 3, 22, 1).getValues().filter(String);

    let destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID").getSheetByName("PO Log");

    let lastA = destSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
    let lastB = destSheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues().filter(String).length;
    let lastC = destSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length;
    let lastD = destSheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues().filter(String).length;
    let lastE = destSheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues().filter(String).length;

    destSheet.getRange(lastA + 1, 1).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange(5, 6).getValue());
    destSheet.getRange(lastB + 1, 2).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange(5, 7).getValue());
    destSheet.getRange(lastC + 1, 3).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange(11, 1).getValue());
    destSheet.getRange(lastD + 1, 4).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange(22, 1).getValue());

    for (let i = 0; i < valuesC.length; i++) {
        destSheet.getRange(lastE + 1, 5, valuesC.length, 1).setValues(valuesC);
    }

    // rest of the code

}
```

#### Explanation

Assuming the following:

- the value from `F5` will be pasted onto the first available row in column `A` in the destination sheet;
- the value from `G5` will be pasted onto the first available row in column `B` in the destination sheet;
- the value from `A11` will be pasted onto the first available row in column `C` in the destination sheet;
- the value from `A22` will be pasted onto the first available row in column `D` in the destination sheet;
- the non-empty values from `C25:C46` will be pasted onto the first available rows in column `E` in the destination sheet;

Then the code above will retrieve each last column from the destination sheet and afterwards paste the values from the source sheet. However, since the `C` column has multiple values that need to be pasted, this is handled differently using a `for` loop.

#### If you also want to check the email...

Then this can be easily achieved by adding an `if` condition with an `alert`:

```
 if (email == "") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Email field is empty. Please input the email!")
  }
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Ui Class - alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String)).